# How to change the column name in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I need to rename the column name of one of the table. I have DB2 database and we are connecting with the database and executing sql queries through Eclipse IDE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Use an ALTER TABLE statement.

```
ALTER TABLE G31.TG31PDIX RENAME COLUMN RECORD_KEY TO RECORD_KEYY;
```

This will only work if you use a version of DB2 that supports this feature.  An older version might be out of luck.  I'm not sure when they added it, but it was after 2004.

Comment: In version 9.7 it was certainly present: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0053723.html

Comment: How do you rename multiple columns at a time? Do you have to repeat the ALTER TABLE piece before every column?