# Rename column on iSeries DB2

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I would like to rename a column in DB2 on the iSeries platform. The link below is related, however, I do not have a primary key or constraint defined on the columns I would like to rename. In addition, I'm not certain that they are on the iSeries as well.
[Rename column in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905278/rename-column-in-db2)

However, I decided to give it a go with the following statement:

`ALTER TABLE MYLIB.MYFILE RENAME COLUMN COL0001 TO COL0002;`

Post execution, I am given the following warning:
[image: DB2 error]
Additionally, I do not see a RENAME COLUMN in the docs:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzatabl.htm

Is this something that is not possible on V7R1 DB2?

Comment: Check out these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905278/rename-column-in-db2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385938/how-to-change-the-column-name-in-db2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `RENAME COLUMN` clause in the `ALTER TABLE` statement in DB2 for IBM i.
You may probably achieve the same with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE MYLIB.MYFILE ADD COLUMN COL0002 ...;
UPDATE MYLIB.MYFILE SET COL0002 = COL0001;
ALTER TABLE MYLIB.MYFILE DROP COLUMN COL0001;
```

Comment: This should work up to the update, but might give an error on the drop.